# FFmpeg Unrecognized option 'x264opts'

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, x264

I'm using FFmpeg for a project concerned DASH (Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP). For the build and installation of ffmpeg I've followed the "Original Guide" [Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#RevertingChangesMadebyThisGuide), using the compile commands in the guide (not the sudo apt-get install ...). Using on the terminal ffmpeg I have the error **Unrecognized option 'x264opts'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found** . I though the cause would be the library libx264, but I have installed it during the procedure. 
Note that the command that give the error is

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -i Helicopter.mp4 -threads 0 -vf "scale=426:240" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -profile:v main -level 4 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -x264opts "keyint=60:min-keyint=60:no-scenecut" -b:v 300k -maxrate 300k -bufsize 600k -r:v 30 -an -y -f mp4 Helicopter_240p_300.mp4`

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Here the complete bash input and output : [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/PXcakdHA)

Comment: Show the full banner of ffmpeg.

Comment: What does it changes? The probleb is the libx264.. this is the pastebin complete issue [link](https://pastebin.com/PXcakdHA)

Comment: If `configuration: --disable-x86asm` is the full config, then you don't have libx264 enabled. You should see `--enable-libx264` as well.

Comment: How can I fix this?